# Error when ChangeNotifierProvider and MaterialPageRoute used together

Tags: flutter, dart

```
            A a = await createA();
            ...
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    ChangeNotifierProvider<A>.value(
                  value: a,
                  child: const NewPage(),
                ),
              ),
            );
```

When I try to use object 'a' as below inside the build function of the NewPage, I am getting below error. Anything wrong with what am I doing?

```
           context.watch<A>()
```

**Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this NewPage Widget**

**This happens because you used a BuildContext that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:**

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using `child` in provider, which means the widget won't build upon the provider.

You should use builder:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<A>.value(
  value: a,
  builder: (context, child) => const NewPage(),
);
```

Now the provider are able to inject the dependency(`A`), and rebuild your desired widget(`NewPage`) with the correct context.